# Failing htaccess clen redirect

Tags: .htaccess

Going to: http://localhost:3000/rr/uu
with:

```
 RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?param=$1&param2=$2
```

Works.

Adding just a parameter:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?param=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
```

and going to :

http://localhost:3000/rr/uu/gg

result in Not Found apache error message. Why ?

Comment: Your rule accepts only 2 perameters

Comment: You can make your comment an answer and I will chose it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule needs 3 capture groups, try :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?(.*)/?(.*)/?$ /index.php?perm=$1&perm2=$1&perm3=$3 [L]
```

Comment: this (and my example) seems to force 3 params or it won't work. Is there way to make it conditional so it will work for 1 to 3 params ?

Comment: @RobertBrax I have updated the code as per your request. last 2 capture groups are optional in the rule now.